Деепричастия - можно ли так писать?
Правильно ли составлено следующее предложение с деепричастиями?
"Слишком много мыслей крутилось в голове, пересекаясь, разбегаясь, образуя водоворот бессвязных ощущений".

"Слишком много мыслей крутилось в голове: пересекаясь, разбегаясь, образуя водоворот бессвязных ощущений". Хотя мысль, это по идее что-то связанное, мне кажется лучше: слишком много чего крутилось...

В качестве варианта:
Слишком много мыслей крутилось в головЕ, // пересекаясь, разбегаясь и образуя водоворот бессвязных ощущЕний.
Пояснение
Правка не грамматическая, а стилистическая. По грамматике нет вопросов, но интонационно желательно разделить предложение на две части.
Пауза там есть, а иначе получится интонация перечисления для глагола и деепричастий.
Использование сильных знаков (тире или двоеточия) мне представляется необоснованным, в то же время замыкающий союз И может объединить ряд деепричастий в отдельную смысловую и интонационную группу.

Спасибо. Я, навернр, неправильно сформулировал вопрос, точнее, не обозначил "проблему". Сомнения были насчет отнесения деепричастий к подлежащему, а оно здесь выражено сочетанием "много мыслей". Т.е. все нормально? "Мысли" стоят не в им. падеже, не согласуются со сказуемым. Получается, что все зависит только от "много". Спасибо.

Спасибо за интересный вопрос, заходите чаще) Дополнительное пояснение по грамматике. Много в знач. числительного, неопределенно большое количество кого-, чего-л..  // Много мыслей – неразложимое сочетание, числовой оборот.  Это единый член предложения, форма И.п. для подлежащего // По Розенталю обычно согласование со сказуемым  делается в ед. числе, но мн. число также возможно, §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте), пункт 12 https://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm
